# Is there a Stack Overflow site with less strict rules allowing multiple ideas at once and 'vague' questions?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I ask questions that don’t fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow)

Is there a Stack Overflow site with less strict rules allowing multiple ideas at once and 'vague' questions?

Questions like "What do you think about" or "Do you agree that", for instance.

"What do you think about the current development of the programming industry" which is vague obviously and not answerable in one sentence.

"Do you agree that brainwave music helps you focus better?"

Both would get downvotes and I am sick of the constant closing and downvotes. If it's never "good enough" tell me where it's good enough and you'll never see me again here.

Comment: And we aren't a forum either.

Comment: How would "Do you agree that .." be a good question? It can only be answered with Yes (suggested by the way of phrasing the question) or No. At best, you get a healthy discussion where all possible aspects are evaluated. At worst, it ends in a never ending discussion with stubborn participants.

Comment: I think for social reasons questions like this are important. If you want approval from others you need to fake a question for others to engage on this site. This cannot be the right approach.

Comment: @user1505034 If you seek the approval of others, ask interesting questions and post interesting answers *within* the scope of the site.

Comment: To me all of my questions are interesting, how should I know what others care about? Not all of them are within the boundaries but they are interesting. No need to remove them. If not here then somewhere else. Do you know like that what I like? No, you don't.

Comment: I do like quality answers here, though and I think you can get quality answers to vague questions aswell, which is why I want to address this community. Barring of course their quality answers only occur when facing discrete issue.

Comment: You know what "we" care about by reading the FAQ. That details the strict guidelines of what "we" as a community like. If your question does not fall within those bounds, "we" don't like it.

Comment: @Bart At least those who wrote the FAQ don't.

Comment: @user1505034 Which is about as official of a "we" you're going to get.

Comment: I don't think the FAQs have changed a lot since you joined 5 months ago, so I very much agree with @Bart here. Also, see the Stack Exchange wide ["About us"](http://stackexchange.com/about): *"We welcome questions that are clear and specific, representing real problems that you face; Stack Exchange is not the place for conversation, opinions, or socializing."*

Answer (score 9):

No, as the philosophy about the quality of questions applies to all of the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Good then I cannot be a se-site then but something else.

Comment: @user1505034 Absolutely, but that would then fall outside the on-topic area of discussion for this site.

Comment: @jolly Wow, I was wondering who went behind that Gravatar...your mod diamond somehow being partially cut off didn't help at all there. :)

Comment: @bart thank random for the gravatar, me for the name =)

Answer (score 6):

Try the [chat room(s)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) of the specific subject, those are more suitable for discussing ideas and opinions.

Comment: Chat rooms are just that, chat rooms. Quickly content is lost in the endless continuation of useless mental garbage being released. I don't want to go *that* low.

Comment: @user1505034 Well that's not very nice.

Comment: @Asad I wasn't talking about your contribution as I do not know you. The last time I joined the chat room people were talking about someone whose kid had issues with his teeth and didn't like to put braces in. That's something I do not need and do not want to know. My attempts to change the topic were simply over"heard", so I left. It was a normal chat experience, all people are writing something without even relating to previous statements. This is the unsightliest form of human interaction.